# How do I delete a login created for a specific user on my SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I have accidentally run the following `T-SQL` command in `SSMS`.

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE LOGIN [XXXXXX\user10] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO
```

How do I cancel this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
DROP LOGIN [XXXXXX\user10]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-login-transact-sql